# Google: how many letters may be in a google search string?

Tags: php

Dumb question, but somehow interesting. Is it just thr $_GET-limit or do they have some other techniques ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2048 is the right answer

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="lst" type="text" name="q" maxlength="2048" value="" title="Search" spellcheck="false">
```

hope so it will help you.

Comment: :) better than do a strlen no?

Answer (score 2):

For the Google Search API:

`There is a limit of 320 characters returned for each meta tag when using getfields.`

**Usage**

```
GET /search?q=[search term]&output=xml&client=test&site=test&getfields=[meta tag name]
```

http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/50/xml_reference.html

Answer (score 1):

LOL. check the HTML input maxlength on google homepage.

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="lst" type="text" name="q" maxlength="2048" value="" title="Search" spellcheck="false">
```